# visual studio code double click speed not using os setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual studio code is not using double click speed set in the OS (at least in windows).
I have it slowed down because i have some problems with my right hand but it doesn't seems to affect it.
Basically I can double click in the OS but not in visual studio code, is there any way to change this?

thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that the behavior of double clicking is customizatable (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2036); it is not immediately obvious whether click speed is included.

Comment: I coldn't find anything related to click speed in the settings, the link is related to selection behaviour more than double clicking

Comment: Is it definitely not using the OS setting, or could it be this bug? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/58976
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128508

Comment: I also have this problem
Could you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting solution!

```
Zoom Out (Ctrl+-) - decrease the Zoom level
```

**The size of the page should be larger than the size of the menu bar that is opened by right clicking**