# In VS Code, Is there a way to turn off automatic word selection on double-click?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I place the cursor in VS Code, I often inadvertently double-click. VS Code uses this to select some block of code -- almost never what I want. Is there a way to turn off this behavior? I can select on my own.

Comment: Question should be asked on a VS-Code help forum, it is not a programming problem suitable for [so]

Comment: @itprorh66 the [on topic help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) clearly states "if your question generally covers software tools commonly used by programmers then you’re in the right place to ask your question"  There are many questions about Visual Studio Code and many other IDEs on Stackoverflow that are similar to this that are perfectly fine.

Comment: This sounds like something you need to fix on the OS level (reject doubleclicks if they're too quick).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't think so. consider https://stackoverflow.com/q/62417706/11107541. also the fact that even when the textual parts of VS Code's editor displays are HTML-based and not canvas-based (though other parts are, such as selection highlighting), the selection obeys rules defined by VS Code, so it's not even Electron/Chromium generic behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. You probably would be interested in the following issue tickets though:

- [Allow changing triple-click (and double-click) behaviour #57633](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/57633)
- more broadly: [Allow customization of mouse shortcuts #3130](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3130)

I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

Also related is [Customisable double click-select behaviour
#2036](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2036), but it's closed, and unfortunately, I can't figure out a way to use `editor.wordSeparators` to make double clicking not select anything or only select one character. Neither setting it to an empty string or to `` `~!@#%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM `` do it. But if your problem is that it's selecting too much, you can probably use that setting to reduce how much is being selected (just not to a single character or to nothing).